# Shell injection - is this secure?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am solving an issue I have with bad performing flash in Firefox under Linux.

I would like to know if the following code is secure. The input is untrusted and I get the feeling that if not sanitized, could be dangerous.

```
#!/bin/bash

#in="vlc://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVpbFMhOAwE"
in=$1;
out=`echo $in | sed -r 's/vlc:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*).*$/\1/g'`;
vlc "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$out";
```

Edit 1: based on Jan Hudec's comments I have come to this

```
#!/bin/bash

#in="vlc://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVpbFMhOAwE"
in=$1;

if [ `expr "$in" : '^vlc://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*$'` -gt 0 ]
then
    vlc "http${in:3}";
fi
```

Edit 2 (likely final):

```
#!/bin/bash

#in="vlc://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVpbFMhOAwE"
in=$1;

if expr "$in" : '^vlc://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*$' >/dev/null 
then
    vlc "http${in:3}";
fi
```

Comment: Note that you can use other characters as the delimiter in sed substitution commands.  For example: `s@vlc://www.youtube.com/watch@\1@g`.  This lets you avoid ugly escaping of slashes, so long as there is some "safe" delimiter to use.

Comment: I would actually skip the process substitution of `expr` and check it's exit code instead (and redirect output to /dev/null). `if expr ...`.

Comment: That's slightly above my skill level, but, as in `if expr "$in" : '^vlc://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*$' >/dev/null` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this particular script can be actually exploited to do anything evil, but only as long as vlc won't do anything evil on a malformed URL starting with correct youtube host, but containing funny stuff. Because the sanitization is totally ineffective.

There are 3 mistakes that together mean almost anything can be passed to vlc and some information about the system may be found using it:

- The first problem is the echo command. Echo is the most irregular command of unix shell,
  behaving very differently in each shell. Use `printf` if you need to pass parameter to
  standard input of a command unmodified.
- Second problem is that it's argument is not quoted (you still have to quote variables
  in command substitution), so it will undergo word splitting and filename generation
  (globbing). The later could be abused to get some information of the system. As long
  as the command only has local effect, this is worthless, but vary of similar mistake
  in anything network-observable. Also some shells (but not bash) might allow some
  side-effects from filename generation in which case it would become dangerous.
- Last the sed will just return the content of `$in` when it does not match and you pass
  it straight to vlc than. It is properly quoted there, so vlc won't interpret it as separate
  URLs or options, only as one, funny, invalid URL. So it is unlikely to be exploitable
  unless using some serious bug in vlc.

I think you should:

1. Check whether the argument is in appropriate format using `expr` command with properly quoted arguments.
2. And abort with error if it does not.
3. Than simply remove the prefix with `${in#*=}` because you already checked the prefix is there and ends with `=`.

Comment: Exactly. Off the top of my head something like `$in="$(rm -rf /)"` might cause a really bad day...

Comment: If `$1` is the literal string `$(rm -rf /)`, as long as `$in` remains quoted in expansions and is never passed to `eval`, the script should be safe. The result of an expansion does not undergo further expansion.

Comment: @chepner: The problem is that `$in` is _not_ quoted when passed to `echo` in that process substitution.

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup: I'm sure you meant `$in='$(rm -rf /)'`. that wouldn't cause any serious problems.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: "doesn't matter". it still won't execute that command. there's no `eval`.

Comment: Also, to answer the actual question, it's *secure*. There are a couple of problems with it, but nothing serious that could actually do any harm. (I'm pretty sure there's going to be someone who, without testing it, thinks I'm wrong, so if you reply, please show the actual input that does any harm. thank you).

Comment: @JanHudec - I agree, that expansion *should* be quoted.

Comment: @chepner: That certainly won't work, no. Only word splitting (useless for exploits) and filename generation will be done. Than it depends of what the particular shell can be made to do in filename generation. Bash not much, but other shells may be able to do a bit more.

Comment: I have updated the code under "edit 1." There seems to be a bit of a debate, I don't have the skill to participate in it, but, expr seems more purpose built for the task than echo piped into sed. Perhaps there will be more agreement with the edit.

Comment: @user166891 there's no need for expr either -- bash can do trimming with parameter expansion, and either regex or pattern tests with `[[ ]]` (and, for that matter, regex groups can be retrieved with BASH_REMATCH, making `[[ $in =~ $re ]]` fully the equivalent of what you're using sed for here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I personally never use bash for interpreting scripts, because there are much faster shells that can be installed as `/bin/sh` (like `ash`/`dash`). And those don't have `[[ ]]` tests. But as long as the question has `#!/bin/bash`, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, there's no need to use `expr`:

```
regex="^vlc://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
if [[ $in =~ $regex ]]; then
```

Comment: Close, but this should also actually return only the `v=` content to be equivalent (maybe using `BASH_REMATCH`?).